# Using 'contains' for _any_ child node - only matches the first child?

Tags: xslt

I have the following input xml:

```
<relations>
<parent>
<child>a</child>
<child>b</child>
<child>c></child>
</parent>
<parent>
<child>x</child>
<child>y</child>
<child>z></child>
</parent>
</relations>
```

And I am interested only in processing 'parent' nodes whose child nodes (any of them) contain a particular string; I have created the following XSLT (1.0) - but this evidently only applies the 'contains' function to the first child only ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="relations" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="relations">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent[ contains(child, 'a') ]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <xsl:text>FOUND A MATCH, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That is: if I but an 'a' or an 'x' in that 'contains' function for my input document, I get a match, but if I put a 'b','c','y' or 'z' - it no longer returns true.

How can I re-write this so that a match counts when *any* child matches the contains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**contains** expects a string as the first argument, so in your statement it will only look at the first **child** element of a **parent**.

Try re-writing it as this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="parent[child[contains(., 'a')]]" />
```

This should find the **parent** who has a **child** element whose text contains 'a'